# how to output the time and date in dompdf?

Tags: php

dompdf output with date and time in the file name. As of now it over writes the current file, which I don't want to happen. I need it to save as a new file, so tot to add time and date at the end of the file name which will be read as a new file.

**Code**

```
private $curDir;

    public function __construct() {
        global $cur_dir;
        $this->curDir = $cur_dir;
    }

    private function getHtml() {
        ob_start();
        include($this->curDir . '/quote-credit.php');
        $retStr = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $retStr;
    }

    public function getPdf() {      
        $html = $this->getHtml();
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream( "credit.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
        $output = $dompdf->output();

        $pdfFileName = $this->curDir.'/credit.pdf';
        file_put_contents($pdfFileName, $output);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a little too obvious and there's something I'm missing but how about...

```
$fn = sprintf('credit-%s.pdf', date('c'));

// ...

$dompdf->stream($fn, ['Attachment' => 0]);

// ...

$pdfFileName = $this->curDir . '/' . $fn;
```